# Script não mostra o mapa

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Estou usando esse *script*:

> https://github.com/ChadKillingsworth/geolocation-marker/releases/tag/v2.0.4

O erro no console é esse:

> "Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError developers.google/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error"js:34:391
>
> "Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys developers.google/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys"

Imagem do erro:

[image: img do erro]

Comment: Marcos, dê uma olhada [nessa minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/149572/35406) em outra pergunta, e clique em executar. Basicamente você precisa criar uma chave para seu projeto no [Console de APIs do Google](https://console.developers.google.com/?hl=pt-br)

Comment: Já criei a api key, o código não tem local para colocar a key, tem alguma api key definida para criar nesse caso? –

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa de uma Chave de API do Google Maps, que pode ser obtida por esse link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Provavelmente em algum lugar do seu script deve ter um campo pra "INSERT_MAPS_API_KEY" algo do gênero, dá uma olhada.

Comment: já criei o código em si não pede nem uma informação para api key, grato.

Answer (score 1):

Após [obter uma chave para o Google Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/get-api-key?hl=pt-br)

Verifique se todas as APIs do Google Maps estão habilitadas no [Console de APIs do Google](https://console.developers.google.com/?hl=pt-br)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também recomendo realizar a leitura deste [comunicado em inglês](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only) no qual são descrito as seguintes informações:

> "Chrome não suporta mais a obtenção de localização do usuário usando a
>   API HTML5 Geolocation a partir de páginas entregues por conexões não
>   seguras. Isto significa que a página que está fazendo a chamada de API
>   de Geolocalização deve ser servido a partir de um contexto seguro ,
>   como HTTPS" .

Comment: http://get-play.org/test/index.html usei o codigo para localização atual da pessoa mas da o mesmo erro do script que usei para postagem desse topico, esse é o script que você me indicou -> http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3653/usando-geolocalizacao-com-html5.aspx  tem alguma ideia oque pode estar acontecendo tenho api key mas o erro persiste

Comment: @MarcosDavidDosSantosSoares dei uma editada na resposta acho que agora ela ficou mais completa.